# Denormalize/Restructure CDISC supplement data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
         USUBJID   IDVAR IDVARVAL      QNAM                        QVAL
0  Dummy-01-0001   AESEQ      1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-15
1  Dummy-01-0002   AESEQ      1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-23
2  Dummy-01-0004   AESEQ      1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-06
3  Dummy-01-0004   AESEQ      2.0  AEdummy1                  2012-03-10
4  Dummy-01-0005   AESEQ      1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-03-10
5  Dummy-01-0001  AESPID        1  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
6  Dummy-01-0002  AESPID        1  dummy2AE     Nervous system disorder
7  Dummy-01-0004  AESPID        2  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
8  Dummy-01-0004  AESPID        1  dummy2AE     Nervous system disorder
9  Dummy-01-0005  AESPID        1  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
```

Above dataframe is just a sample, please use following code to get some more data into dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'USUBJID': {0: 'Dummy-01-0001', 1: 'Dummy-01-0002', 2: 'Dummy-01-0004', 3: 'Dummy-01-0004', 4: 'Dummy-01-0005', 5: 'Dummy-01-0007', 6: 'Dummy-01-0008', 7: 'Dummy-01-0008', 8: 'Dummy-01-0010', 9: 'Dummy-01-0010', 10: 'Dummy-01-0011', 11: 'Dummy-01-0011', 12: 'Dummy-01-0013', 13: 'Dummy-01-0013', 14: 'Dummy-01-0014', 15: 'Dummy-01-0016', 16: 'Dummy-01-0016', 17: 'Dummy-01-0019', 18: 'Dummy-01-0001', 19: 'Dummy-01-0002', 20: 'Dummy-01-0004', 21: 'Dummy-01-0004', 22: 'Dummy-01-0005', 23: 'Dummy-01-0007', 24: 'Dummy-01-0008', 25: 'Dummy-01-0008', 26: 'Dummy-01-0010', 27: 'Dummy-01-0010', 28: 'Dummy-01-0011', 29: 'Dummy-01-0011', 30: 'Dummy-01-0013', 31: 'Dummy-01-0013', 32: 'Dummy-01-0014', 33: 'Dummy-01-0016', 34: 'Dummy-01-0016', 35: 'Dummy-01-0017', 36: 'Dummy-01-0017', 37: 'Dummy-01-0019'}, 'IDVAR': {0: 'AESEQ', 1: 'AESEQ', 2: 'AESEQ', 3: 'AESEQ', 4: 'AESEQ', 5: 'AESEQ', 6: 'AESEQ', 7: 'AESEQ', 8: 'AESEQ', 9: 'AESEQ', 10: 'AESEQ', 11: 'AESEQ', 12: 'AESEQ', 13: 'AESEQ', 14: 'AESEQ', 15: 'AESEQ', 16: 'AESEQ', 17: 'AESEQ', 18: 'AESPID', 19: 'AESPID', 20: 'AESPID', 21: 'AESPID', 22: 'AESPID', 23: 'AESPID', 24: 'AESPID', 25: 'AESPID', 26: 'AESPID', 27: 'AESPID', 28: 'AESPID', 29: 'AESPID', 30: 'AESPID', 31: 'AESPID', 32: 'AESPID', 33: 'AESPID', 34: 'AESPID', 35: 'AESPID', 36: 'AESPID', 37: 'AESPID'}, 'IDVARVAL': {0: '1.0', 1: '1.0', 2: '1.0', 3: '2.0', 4: '1.0', 5: '1.0', 6: '1.0', 7: '2.0', 8: '1.0', 9: '2.0', 10: '1.0', 11: '2.0', 12: '1.0', 13: '2.0', 14: '1.0', 15: '1.0', 16: '2.0', 17: '1.0', 18: '1', 19: '1', 20: '2', 21: '1', 22: '1', 23: '1', 24: '1', 25: '2', 26: '2', 27: '1', 28: '1', 29: '2', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '1', 33: '1', 34: '2', 35: '1', 36: '2', 37: '1'}, 'QNAM': {0: 'AEdummy1', 1: 'AEdummy1', 2: 'AEdummy1', 3: 'AEdummy1', 4: 'AEdummy1', 5: 'AEdummy1', 6: 'AEdummy1', 7: 'AEdummy1', 8: 'AEdummy1', 9: 'AEdummy1', 10: 'AEdummy1', 11: 'AEdummy1', 12: 'AEdummy1', 13: 'AEdummy1', 14: 'AEdummy1', 15: 'AEdummy1', 16: 'AEdummy1', 17: 'AEdummy1', 18: 'dummy2AE', 19: 'dummy2AE', 20: 'dummy2AE', 21: 'dummy2AE', 22: 'dummy2AE', 23: 'dummy2AE', 24: 'dummy2AE', 25: 'dummy2AE', 26: 'dummy2AE', 27: 'dummy2AE', 28: 'dummy2AE', 29: 'dummy2AE', 30: 'dummy2AE', 31: 'dummy2AE', 32: 'dummy2AE', 33: 'dummy2AE', 34: 'dummy2AE', 35: 'dummy2AE', 36: 'dummy2AE', 37: 'dummy2AE'}, 'QVAL': {0: '2012-02-15', 1: '2012-02-23', 2: '2012-02-06', 3: '2012-03-10', 4: '2012-03-10', 5: '2012-02-08', 6: '2012-03-18', 7: '2012-03-07', 8: '2012-02-01', 9: '2012-01-10', 10: '2012-01-19', 11: '2012-03-28', 12: '2012-02-19', 13: '2012-02-14', 14: '2012-03-13', 15: '2012-03-08', 16: '2012-02-05', 17: '2012-03-18', 18: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 19: 'Nervous system disorder', 20: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 21: 'Nervous system disorder', 22: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 23: 'Vascular disorders', 24: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 25: 'Vascular disorders', 26: 'Nervous system disorder', 27: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 28: 'Nervous system disorder', 29: 'Nervous system disorder', 30: 'Nervous system disorder', 31: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 32: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 33: 'Vascular disorders', 34: 'Gastrointestinal disorders', 35: 'Nervous system disorder', 36: 'Nervous system disorder', 37: 'Vascular disorders'}})
```

Let's understand the structure a bit. `IDVAR` holds the variable name and `IDVARVAL` holds its values, and `QNAM` holds another variable name and `QVAL` holds the corresponding value.
This structure, in the domain I'm working is called normalized structure, I know it's weird though.

I want to get this data in the following form:

```
         USUBJID   AESEQ AESPID    AEdummy1      dummy2AE
0  Dummy-01-0001   1.0      1      2012-02-15    Gastrointestinal disorders
1  Dummy-01-0002   1.0      1      2012-02-23    Nervous system disorder
2  Dummy-01-0004   1.0      2      2012-02-06    Gastrointestinal disorders
3  Dummy-01-0004   2.0      1      2012-03-10    Nervous system disorder
4  Dummy-01-0005   1.0      1      2012-03-10    Gastrointestinal disorders
```

If I'd have to do it for `QNAM` and `QVAL` only, there is no problem, I can easily do it using pandas' pivot as follows:

```
df.pivot(
        index=['USUBJID', 'IDVARVAL', 'IDVAR'], 
         columns='QNAM', 
         values='QVAL'
).reset_index()
```

Even for this problem, I can use some sort of masking, but I know that is not going to be the most efficient approach since this data is going to have thousands or sometimes millions of records.

Please be noted that: The combination of `USUBJID`, and `IDVARVAL` for an `IDVAR` should map to the value of `QVAL` for a `QNAM`. That being said, some of the records for `AESEQ`, `AESPID`, `AEdummy1`, and `dummy2AE` could be NaN or empty for the output DataFrame. In other words, for the above sample, `Dummy-01-0001` and `AESEQ=1.0` uniquely identifies `AEdummy1 = 2012-02-15`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us try with `unstacking` followed by `concat`:

```
s  = df.set_index([df.groupby('IDVAR').cumcount(), 'USUBJID'])
s1 = s.set_index('IDVAR', append=True)['IDVARVAL'].unstack()
s2 = s.set_index('QNAM',  append=True)['QVAL'].unstack()

out = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).reset_index(level=1)
```

#### Explanations

Group the dataframe on `IDVAR` and use `cumcount` to create a sequential counter to uniquely identify the rows per `IDVAR` group, then set this counter along with the column `USUBJID` as the index of the dataframe:

```
>>> s
                  IDVAR  IDVARVAL      QNAM                        QVAL
  USUBJID                                                              
0 Dummy-01-0001   AESEQ       1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-15
1 Dummy-01-0002   AESEQ       1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-23
2 Dummy-01-0004   AESEQ       1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-02-06
3 Dummy-01-0004   AESEQ       2.0  AEdummy1                  2012-03-10
4 Dummy-01-0005   AESEQ       1.0  AEdummy1                  2012-03-10
0 Dummy-01-0001  AESPID       1.0  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
1 Dummy-01-0002  AESPID       1.0  dummy2AE     Nervous system disorder
2 Dummy-01-0004  AESPID       2.0  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
3 Dummy-01-0004  AESPID       1.0  dummy2AE     Nervous system disorder
4 Dummy-01-0005  AESPID       1.0  dummy2AE  Gastrointestinal disorders
```

Now for each columns `IDVARVAL` and `QVAL` update the index by appending the corresponding columns `IDVAR` and `QNAM` then `unstack` to reshape:

```
>>> s1

  IDVAR          AESEQ  AESPID
  USUBJID                     
0 Dummy-01-0001    1.0     1.0
1 Dummy-01-0002    1.0     1.0
2 Dummy-01-0004    1.0     2.0
3 Dummy-01-0004    2.0     1.0
4 Dummy-01-0005    1.0     1.0

>>> s2

  QNAM             AEdummy1                    dummy2AE
  USUBJID                                              
0 Dummy-01-0001  2012-02-15  Gastrointestinal disorders
1 Dummy-01-0002  2012-02-23     Nervous system disorder
2 Dummy-01-0004  2012-02-06  Gastrointestinal disorders
3 Dummy-01-0004  2012-03-10     Nervous system disorder
4 Dummy-01-0005  2012-03-10  Gastrointestinal disorders
```

Finally, `concat` the above unstacked frames `s1` and `s2` along `axis=1` to get the desired result:

```
>>> out

         USUBJID  AESEQ  AESPID    AEdummy1                    dummy2AE
0  Dummy-01-0001    1.0     1.0  2012-02-15  Gastrointestinal disorders
1  Dummy-01-0002    1.0     1.0  2012-02-23     Nervous system disorder
2  Dummy-01-0004    1.0     2.0  2012-02-06  Gastrointestinal disorders
3  Dummy-01-0004    2.0     1.0  2012-03-10     Nervous system disorder
4  Dummy-01-0005    1.0     1.0  2012-03-10  Gastrointestinal disorders
```

Answer (score 5):

You could reshape the data with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html), create a counter with [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create a unique index, [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the data, and do some final cleanup to get something similar to your expected output:

```
(
    df.pivot_longer(["USUBJID"],
                    names_pattern=["IDVAR$|QNAM$", "IDVARVAL$|QVAL$"],
                    names_to=["variables", "values"])
    .assign(counter=lambda df: df.groupby(["USUBJID", "variables"]).cumcount())
    .pivot(["USUBJID", "counter"], "variables", "values")
    .droplevel("counter")
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)

         USUBJID AESEQ AESPID    AEdummy1                    dummy2AE
0  Dummy-01-0001   1.0    1.0  2012-02-15  Gastrointestinal disorders
1  Dummy-01-0002   1.0    1.0  2012-02-23     Nervous system disorder
2  Dummy-01-0004   1.0    2.0  2012-02-06  Gastrointestinal disorders
3  Dummy-01-0004   2.0    1.0  2012-03-10     Nervous system disorder
4  Dummy-01-0005   1.0    1.0  2012-03-10  Gastrointestinal disorders
```

Comment: for the first time I am seeing `pivot_longer` function. +1 this is something new for me